# Why do I get an error when using list in python?

Tags: python, list, calculator

I am trying to do the following CodingBat problem: [no_teen_sum](http://codingbat.com/prob/p100347)  but keep getting an error in line 2:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
teens = [13,14,17,18,19]
  if a in teens:
    return b + c
  elif b in teens:
    return a + c
  elif c in teens:
    return a + b
  elif a in teens and b in teens:
    return c
  elif a in teens and c in teens:
    return b
  elif b in teens and c in teens:
    return a
```

Comment: indent error - indent your second line to line up with your third

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an indentation problem. Remember to always use 4 spaces for indentation, be consistent.

Here's the fixed version:

```
def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
    teens = [13,14,17,18,19]
    if a in teens:
        return b + c
    elif b in teens:
        return a + c
    elif c in teens:
        return a + b
    elif a in teens and b in teens:
        return c
    elif a in teens and c in teens:
        return b
    elif b in teens and c in teens:
        return a
```

Comment: Did not see that one :) Thank you!

Comment: @user2357 consider using a smart editor like `pycharm`, or `sublime` with a special plugin. It would help you a lot by highlighting errors while you type.

Comment: I have pycharm but it isn't working properly for some reason so I stopped using it and started using IDLE. Will try sublime, hopefully it works.